# v-for for nested object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Trying to do a `v-for` for nested object.

```
const products = {
  Shorts: "/shorts",
  Socks: "/socks",
  Shoes: {
    "Shoes4men": "/shoes4men",
    "Shoes4women": "/shoes4women",
    "Shoes4kids": "/shoes4kids",
  },
}
```

In frontend then:

```
<div v-for="(link, product) in products" :key="product" :value="link">
{{ product }} {{ link }}
</div>
```

This works for the outer links (Shorts, Socks, Shoes), but how to show the `Shoes4men`, `Shoes4women` and `Shoes4kids` texts and links too under the `Shoes` category with `v-for`? I tried with `v-if` and `v-for` in the same element but that did not work (also seems bad practise I read).

Comment: How many levels of nesting do you have to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v-if and v-for on the same element is bad practice, but it's not a problem to nest a v-for element inside a v-if element.  Use v-if to determine if the product has more inner products (i.e. is an object), then nest a v-for to display those inner products, else just display the current "outer" product

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(link, product) in products" :key="product">
    <div v-if="isObject(product)">
      <div v-for="(innerLink, innerProduct) in products[product]" :key="innerProduct">
        product: {{ innerProduct }} link: {{ innerLink }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>product: {{ product }} link: {{ link }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
const products = {
  Shorts: "/shorts",
  Socks: "/socks",
  Shoes: {
    "Shoes4men": "/shoes4men",
    "Shoes4women": "/shoes4women",
    "Shoes4kids": "/shoes4kids",
  },
};

function isObject(product) {
  return typeof products[product] === "object";
}
</script>
```

[example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-galois-hmtstx?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a `v-if` on the same element that you have `v-for` on it and in other hand you do'nt want to use an element like `div`, you can use `template` tag that has `v-if`, something like that:

```
<div v-for="(item, itemIndex)" :key="itemIndex">
    <template v-if="isOject(item)">
        <!-- do your job -->
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <!-- do another job -->
    </template>
</div>
```